# how can use from "child_process" module in +angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

i try to use from 'cihld_process' module in my angular app.

like this

```
import { spawn } from "child_process";

console.log(spawn) // spawn = undefind
```

But spawn is undefined for me.

I want to use this package to use Powershell commands in my program.
If you have a solution, please help me.

Comment: `child_process` comes from the node environment. Normally angular is using webpack and targeting browser clients and you can not use such functions. Don't know what your exact use case is here but you can modify your `webpack.config` and use `"target": "node"`. This will work in desktop environemnts like Electron

Comment: @Enak I don't know how to apply these settings.
I really want to execute a powershell command when a button is clicked.

Comment: In which environment is your app executed? If the answer is "a browser" then it will not work. Shell execution from browsers by an arbitrary script is a security issue and therefore not permitted and will not work.